# Java Reflection API: How to know the type of field in a Java class

Tags: java

I am trying a certain program where I have to use Java Reflection API. Specifically, I need to know the actual data type of the fields in a given class. The way I found for doing this is to use the java.lang.reflect.Field class. This class exposes methods like `getGenericType().getTypeName()` and `getType().getTypeName()`. These return `java.lang.String` representation for the fully qualified names of the referenced data types in the class. For instance if my class is as follows:

```
class MyClass{Integer age;}
```

For the above scenario I would get that the data type of "age" is "`java.lang.Integer` type in `String representation`. However, the String representation would not be of much use in my case since I need the actual Integer data type not just an textual/String representation of its name. Is there any way to do so.

Comment: The `getType()` method of `java.lang.reflect.Field` already gives you the type, in the form of an instance of `Class`. What else exactly do you think you need?

Comment: Yeah, couldn't you just get rid of `.getTypeName()` and be done with it?

Comment: I solved a similar proble using `Class clazz = field.getDeclaringClass();`

Comment: @Skizzo That gets you the class that contains the field, not the class of the field itself. The OP seems to need to get the type of the field itself.

Comment: Thanks every one for your inputs.

Comment: Thanks every one for your inputs.

@Jesper, you are correct that the `Field.getType()` would give me the Class representation of actual Data Type. But how to extract that actual data type from the `Class` representation; I do not think that there is any method in Class API which gives access to the data type which it represents. Although, there are methods like `getSimpleName()` and `getTypeName()`, but again they return String representation of the actual Data Type. It would immensely help me if there be some method on whose return type I may utilize `instanceof` operator, for instance.

Comment: The `Class` *is* the representation of the datatype. Note that you are dealing with a *runtime* representation of the data type. There's no way to get a compile-time representation because you don't know the type beforehand (at compile time). Instead of `instanceof` you use methods of the `Class` object, for example `isInstance()` or `isAssignableFrom()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the class returned by Field getType method. See the example code bellow:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

    public class Main {

      public static void main(String[] args) {
        Field[] declaredFields = MyClass.class.getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field declaredField : declaredFields) {
          Class<?> fieldType = declaredField.getType();
          String result=fieldType.getName();
          System.out.println(result);
        }
      }

    }
```

But be careful with primitive data types (example: boolean). In this case the fieldType.getName() function returns a uninstantiated string (boolean).
You can handle it differently. The list of internal data types is [here](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch02_04.htm).

Comment: Primitive type ``Class`` objects return *uninstantiated* ``String``s? To handle primitive types, you can make use of ``Class#isPrimitive``; the link you provided is missing ``void.class``/``Void.TYPE``.